# how to get the notification when user press on "Send" button in email composer

Tags: android

I am using below code to launch the email composer.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, email_chooser_title));
```

After launches the email composer , when the user hits on the "Send" button , I want execute some of my code.

Pl. let me know how can I get that notification.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the android email body then its android defoult page .you can not handle the click event of the send button ..but for that you need to create your own layout and the need to send the mail using the javax.mail api

this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app) you can check out how to make it